# How to update a pyspark.sql.Row object in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I update a value in a `pyspark.sql.Row` object?

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

Record = Row('first','last')
start_row = Record('james','smith')
print(f"Sarting Row Object: {start_row}")
updated_row = start_row.first = 'john'
```

Gives an Exception:

```
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-4099832519586966> in <module>
      4 start_row = Record('james','smith')
      5 print(f"Sarting Row Object: {start_row}")
----> 6 updated_row = start_row.first = 'john'


/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.py in __setattr__(self, key, value)
   1578     def __setattr__(self, key, value):
   1579         if key != '__fields__':
-> 1580             raise Exception("Row is read-only")
   1581         self.__dict__[key] = value
   1582 

Exception: Row is read-only
```

I understand `Row` is read-only. This is a solution I came up with.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
Record = Row('first','last')
start_row = Record('james','smith')
print(f"Sarting Row Object: {start_row}")

def update_spark_row(row,update):
    """pyspar.sql.Row is immutable. Have not found an elegant way to update pyspark.sql.Row objects."""
    row_as_dict = row.asDict() # convert to dict
    row_as_dict[update[0]] = update[1] # make update in dict
    keys = list(row_as_dict.keys()) # get dict keys
    values = list(row_as_dict.values()) # get dict values
    NewRow = Row(*keys) # create new row object
    new_row = NewRow(*values) # populate row object with values
    
    return new_row

end_row = update_spark_row(rec1,('first','jimmy'))
print(f"Ending Row Object: {end_row}")
```

Gives desired results:

```
Sarting Row Object: Row(first='james', last='smith')
Ending Row Object: Row(first='jimmy', last='smith')
```

This snippet works but I feel like there should be an elegant solution. I don't want to create a DataFrame. Alternatively I could use `namedtuple` or `dataclass` but since I'm using PySpark I wanted to use `Row`.

**Use Case:**

I have several Spark Jobs that need to write data to an audit log Table. Concurrent writes (updates) to a spark DF or Table are not feasible. My plan is to let each job keep track of its own `Row` object and then append them to the Table as a last step after all jobs are complete.  Appending a table can be concurrent.

After writing this I suppose I could just use a DataFrame but I would like to know if there is a way that I can use `Row`. Altering data in `namedtuple` or `dataclass` is easy and readable. Editing each DF is a bit more verbose. I guess it's a case of programmer stubbornness.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track. Converting Row to dict first and then recreate the Row object. But the update could be simpler:

One line option:

```
updated_row = Row(**{**start_row.asDict(), **{'first': 'john'}})

print(updated_row)
# Row(first='john', last='smith')
```

Option two:

```
d = start_row.asDict()
d.update({'first': 'john'})
updated_row = Row(**d)

print(updated_row)
# Row(first='john', last='smith')
```